# Converting Mixed Character C String to Lower Case

Tags: c

I am running into a wall here because I don't see how I can iterate over the string and use the tolower() function without severely breaking my dynamically allocating array. Any advice would be suggested.

```
while (fscanf(file, "%s", str) != EOF) { 
    //doubles the word_alloc/str_array if we have more words than allocated
    if(ThreadData.word_count >= ThreadData.word_alloc) {
        ThreadData.word_alloc *= 2;
        ThreadData.str_array =(char **) realloc(ThreadData.str_array, sizeof(char*) * ThreadData.word_alloc);
    }       
    ThreadData.str_array[ThreadData.word_count] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str) + 1));
    strcpy(ThreadData.str_array[ThreadData.word_count], str);
    ++ThreadData.word_count;
}
```

Comment: The two operations are orthogonal. Why would iterating over the array have anything to do with its allocation?

Comment: BTW, you have a buffer overflow vulnerability in there with `"%s"`.

Comment: `fscanf` does not really get you a string, it gets you non-whitespace, and basically loses you all information about the actual whitespace. Don't use `fscanf` for situations like these, use `fgets`. Also don't use `malloc` + 1 and then `strcpy`, use `strdup` instead.

Comment: @Dúthomhas could you tell me more about the buffer overflow vulnerability?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%25s+scanf+vulnerability

Comment: @Dúthomhas I follow with iterating over the individual strings not having anything to do with copying the words into my str_array but I am not sure how to get that lower case word into the char array at that point. If I do a for loop to iterate over str and run tolower() on each of them, how would I reconstruct str and then get that into my array? (if that makes sense)

Comment: Can you not just modify the array data in-place?

Comment: @Dúthomhas Thanks for the info on the vulnerability! Will  update accordingly. Also, I not entirely sure how to modify the array data in-place.. I'm a little stuck there.

Comment: You may want to consider making the string lowercase BEFORE adding it to the collection. I'm guessing you want a list of **unique** words. How many entries do you want for this 'sentence': "Fox fox foX FOX"? Maybe just "run along" the entire string making everything lowercase BEFORE chopping it up into "words".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is helpful to have a utility function to lowercase/uppercase/titlecase/whatever you want to do to your string, such as:

```
#include <ctype.h>

char * lowercase( char * s )
{
  for (char * p = s;  *p;  ++p)
  {
    *p = tolower( *p );
  }
  return s;
}
```

Now, since your data is an array of *strings*, just use the function on each string in your data. With the function defined as it is above, you can do it in-line with your copy:

```
ThreadData.str_array[ThreadData.word_count] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str) + 1));
lowercase(strcpy(ThreadData.str_array[ThreadData.word_count], str));
++ThreadData.word_count;
```

Remember to keep a good reference handy:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/c
  A very good one, but very technical. Takes some time to get used to reading it.
- https://cplusplus.com/reference/
  Gets pooh-poohed all the time, but isn’t all that bad. Very much easier for the beginner to follow.

Comment: Eureka!! Thank you so much! That function call was the exact solution to what I was trying to figure out. You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score -3):

`alternative without using tolower library`

If you want to convert a word from upper case to lower case, you can use the ASCII table.

Here my program to convert it !

`main.h`

```c
#ifndef _HEADER_H_
#define _HEADER_H_

void fill_str(char*);
void convert_to_lower_case(char*);

#endif
```

`main.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.h"

int main(){
    int size = 15; // Size of your string
    char* str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    fill_str(str);
    convert_to_lower_case(str);
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}

void fill_str(char* str){
    printf("Enter your word : ");
    scanf("%s", str);
}

void convert_to_lower_case(char* str){
    int i = 0;
    while(str[i] != '\0'){
        if( (int)str[i] >= 65 && (int)str[i] <= 90){ // We are verifying if the ascii code of a character is in upper case
            int ascii = str[i] + 32; // Example: ASCII code of "A" => 65 and "a" => 97. So 97 - 65 = 32;
            str[i] = (char) ascii;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, don’t do that. Use a library function, like [tolower](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower).